# Precision of mapping floating point numbers to integer screen coordinates

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL, vertices are specified between -1.0 and 1.0 range in NDC and then are mapped to the actual screen. But isn't it possible that with very large screen resolution it becomes impossible to specify the exact pixel location on a screen with this limited floating point value range?

So, mathematically, how large should be the screen resolution to that happen?

Answer (score 2):

A standard (IEEE 754) 32-bit float has 24 bits of precision in the mantissa. 23 bits are stored, plus an implicit leading 1. Since we're looking at a range of -1.0 to 1.0 here, we can also include the sign bit when estimating the precision. So that gives 25 bits of precision.

25 bits of precision is enough to cover 2^25 values. 2^25 = 33,554,432. So with float precision, we could handle a resolution of about 33,554,432 x 33,554,432 pixels. I think we're safe for a while!

Comment: I don't think having 2^25 different values means every value is mapped to every pixels in the same resolution. You can check out the exact mapping function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374202(v=vs.85).aspx). What I want to know is the lowest resolution that at least one pixel can't be exactly specified by the mapping function.

Answer (score 2):

#### Generally the coordinates used for rasterization are not floating-point at all.

They are fixed-point with a few bits reserved for subpixel accuracy (you absolutely need this since pixel coverage for things like triangles is based on distance from pixel center).

[image: Pixel Coverage]

The amount of subpixel precision you are afforded really depends on the value of `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS`. But if `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS` did not exist, then for sure, it would make sense to use floating-point pixel coordinates since you would want to support a massive (potentially unknown) range of coordinates.

In the minimum OpenGL implementation, there must be 4-bits of sub-pixel precision (`GL_SUBPIXEL_BITS`), so if your GPU used 16-bit for raster coordinates that would give you 12-bit (integer) + 4-bit (fractional) to spread across `GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS` (the value would probably be **4096** for 12.4 fixed-point). Such an implementation would limit the integer coordinates to the range [**0**,**4095**] and would divide each of those integer coordinates into 16 sub-pixel positions.

Comment: The OP was concerned about the precision of the NDC. Wouldn't you expect those to still be in float precision? Once you start rasterizing, things obviously change, but that's not what the question was about. At least the way I read it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: That did not seem relevant to me, because `MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS` already confines you into a space small enough that the [**-1.0**,**1.0**] NDC mapping is not going to run out of precision and in fact allows for subpixel precision. He was asking about very large screen resolutions, but you're generally limited to 32768x32768 in the most advanced implementations.